# Translating rails queries for sqlite

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

How would i translate these mysql queries to work with sqlite3?:

```
self.find(:first, :conditions => ['concat(first_name, \' \', middle_names, \' \', last_name) = ?', name])

self.find(:all, :conditions => ['(concat(first_name, \' \', last_name) LIKE ?) OR (concat(first_name, \' \', middle_names, \' \', last_name) LIKE ?)', "%#{name}%", "%#{name}%"])
```

Comment: You might consider denormalizing that table so as to keep the full name as a separate *indexed* field, or creating a view, so as to avoid having to do that concatenation operation over and over. (FWIW, splitting names up for databases is fraught with trouble anyway. There are many people for whom their `first_name` is their `family_name` after all, to name just one of the multitude of problems in this area.)

Comment: Hi, thankfully the school I'm writing this for allready deals with first and last names, so they'll work out that end of it! All my data comes from csv imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little google search could have helped: http://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+concat

In SQLite the concat operator is `||`. and for easier reading of string with single quotes `'` I would enclose these strings with double quotes `"`, so you don't need so much escaping:

```
self.find(:first, :conditions => ["first_name || ' ' || middle_names || ' ' || last_name = ?", name])

self.find(:all, :conditions => ["(first_name || ' ' || last_name LIKE ?) OR (first_name, ' ', middle_names || ' ' || last_name LIKE ?)", "%#{name}%", "%#{name}%"])
```

Answer (score 0):

|| is the SQLite concatenation operator. So this'll probably work:

```
self.find(:first, :conditions => ['first_name || \' \' || middle_names || \' \' || last_name = ?', name])
self.find(:all, :conditions => ['(first_name || \' \' || last_name LIKE ?) OR (first_name || \' \' || middle_names || \' \' || last_name LIKE ?)', "%#{name}%", "%#{name}%"])
```